# Pandas Loop through list of Data Frames and Change Index

Tags: python, pandas

This is a basic quesion, but I want to loop through a list of data frames and for each data frame, set the index as one of the columns in the data frame.  The issue with the code below is that it doesn't save the data frame with a new index.  How do I format this For loop so that the dataframes are permanently changed outside of the for loop? Thanks.

```
dflist = [df_1, df_2, df_3]

for i in dflist:
    i = i.set_index('column_2')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have probably guessed, i is just a temporary value. Use i as only an index using enumerate

```
for i, df in enumerate(dflist):
dflist[i] = dflist[i].set_index('column_2'))
```

Comment: Yes!  Great response.  Thanks for your input.  That makes significantly more sense.

Comment: The only reason to do like this is if you create a new list with dataframes as the runtime will have to create a dataframe and copy it to the list and gc the old item at that index anyway. Then it is better to use inplace, but use sparingly as immutable semantics are easier to reason about.

Comment: True.  I'll give both a go to see what works better for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
for i in dflist:
    i.set_index('column_2', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the in place option:
`i = i.set_index('column_2', inplace=True)`

Comment: Assigning the df in the loop will just give you an unnecessary copy that is immediately gc:ed at end of loop scope.