# python - drop duplicated index in place in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a list of dataframes:

```
all_df = [df1, df2, df3]
```

I would like to remove rows with duplicated indices in all dataframes in the list, such that the changes are reflected in the original dataframes *df1*, *df2* and *df3*.
I tried to do

```
for df in all_df:
    df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
```

But the changes are only applied in the list, not on the original dataframes.

Essentially, I want to avoid doing the following:

```
df1 = df1[~df1.index.duplicated()]
df2 = df2[~df2.index.duplicated()]
df3 = df3[~df3.index.duplicated()]
all_df = [df1,df2,df3]
```

Comment: answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812564/looping-through-a-list-of-pandas-dataframes and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630805/pandas-loop-through-list-of-data-frames-and-change-index. As to why: `df` looks at a new frame each time in the loop, forgetting the old one.

Comment: Thanks. These other questions are indeed related but do not answer my question completely.

Comment: As it stands they exactly answer your question. In case you didn't notice, the answer below repeats those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need recreate list of DataFrames:

```
all_df = [df[~df.index.duplicated()] for df in all_df]
```

Or:

```
for i, df in enumerate(all_df):
    all_df[i] = df[~df.index.duplicated()]

print (all_df[0])
```

---

EDIT: If name of dictionary is important use dictionary of DataFrames, but also inplace modification `df1, df2` is not here, need select by keys of dicts:

```
d = {'price': df1, 'volumes': df2}

d  = {k: df[~df.index.duplicated()] for k, df in all_df.items()}

print (d['price'])
```

Comment: Thanks. This will not remove rows in the original dataframes df1, df2, df3 though, right? It will only change what is in the list all_df. I would like to apply the changes also to the original dataframes df1, df2 and df3.

Comment: @Camille - but why? I see no reason.

Comment: @Camille - you need forget for `df1, df2, df3` - working with list, use function for list.

Comment: Because in the rest of my code, I sometimes do operations on all dataframes, in which case I use the list all_df, and sometimes do operations only on some of them.

Comment: @Camille - I think no reason for use it. instead `df1`, `df2` (it is forgotten) is necessary use `all_df[0]` , `all_df[1]` and use it instead `df1, df2`

Comment: My original dataframes have explicit names that are helpful to me (for example, df1 is actually called prices, df2 volumes, and so on) so I would like to keep using these names instead of all_df[0], ...
Writing this, it occurs to me that I could use a dict of dataframes instead of a list and give a name to the dataframes in that way

Comment: @Camille - understand, why not use dictionary of dict?